# Named? parameters in templates, functions

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any update in the upcoming C++0x standard on named parameters in templates and/or functions?  For example, I would like to be able to write the following:

having defined previously:

```
template<class T = int,class Policy_1, class Policy_2>
class X
{
};
```

then in main:

```
X<Policy_2: NoReturn> x;
```

this same with functions; having:

```
void f(int arg_1 = 0, int arg_2 = 1, int arg_3 = 2)
{
}
```

then in main:

```
f(arg_3: 55);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For functions you can use the *Named Parameters Idiom* (in both C++98 and C++0x).

See C++ FAQ item [10.20 What is the "Named Parameter Idiom"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.20).

For template arguments I think you can use the idea of wrapping, using "type carrier" types that by their type encode which template argument they are. It gets complex. You might check out the Boost Parameters library for ideas, but essentially, for template arguments I do not think it's worth spending time on (not to mention actually using)  --  it's academic.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I have found a lot of uses for it though.  When working with policy based design, where there can be 10 or more template parameters, it's VERY helpful.  Boost.Parameter creates messy implementation code, but clean and easy to use interfaces.

Comment: @Noah: the MPL is sufficient for this (coupled with the type carrier idea). Another solution I have found is simply asking for a `tag` inner-type to be defined in each policy that identifies which category it belongs to. Both are relatively lean.

Answer (score 9):

Not with that syntax and though it becomes easier to USE such constructs, creating them is rather messy.

See Boost.Parameter

You end up with

```
typedef template_by_named< policy1<type1>, policy2<type2> > x;
```

and

```
f(param_b = 23, param_d = 42)
```

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2015/03/named-optional-template-parameters-compile-time.html) describes a technique that can be used to emulate named template parameters.

Example syntax:

```
enum class bars { bar1, bar2, bar3 };

// Omitted definitions of get_value, is_present, get_type, a, b, c and d.

template <typename... Args>
struct foo {
    static constexpr auto A = get_value<a<1>, Args...>::value;
    static constexpr auto B = get_value<b<bars::bar2>, Args...>::value;
    static constexpr auto C = is_present<c, Args...>::value;

    using D = typename get_type<d<char>, Args...>::value;
};

// Client code
foo<d<float>, a<42>> f;
// f::A equals to 42;
// f::B equals to defaulted bars::bar2;
// f::C equals to false, because c is not present among temlate arguments;
// f::D equals to float
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not going to work in C++0x.

Answer (score -5):

The rest of us just used argument structs and got over it. And no.

Comment: I would point out http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html