# C++ Templates: override some, but not all, default arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, default-arguments

When I come across a template with several default arguments, e.g.

```
template<typename ID = int, typename PAYLOAD = std::string>
class Foo{};
```

Is there a way for me to override just a few of the default arguments, instead of all of them?

I.e. instead of writing the following to create a class that uses an integer instead of a `std::string` for the `PAYLOAD` parameter,

```
typedef Foo<int,int> Bar;
```

Can I write something similar to:

```
typedef Foo<PAYLOAD=int> Bar;
```

I am dealing with another team's pre-defined templates with a lot of default arguments, and being able to use the second method seems like it would improve the clarity of my code.

Looking at the documentation and other questions on StackOverflow, it does not seem to be possible, but I was wondering if someone could explain why this isn't a feature?

Comment: Afaik this is only possible in Python for example (maybe also in other script languages). In C++ there is no way to do this I would be aware of.

Comment: The are workarounds, e.g. [boost.parameter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html#class-template-parameter-support), see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4209326/

Comment: You can also use some builder pattern to achieve a syntax close to: `Foo_builder::Payload<int>::type`, or specifying both arguments `Foo_builder::ID<double>::Payload<int>::type` (in any order).

Comment: Are all the arguments types?  Would override by index be ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Design and Evolution of C++, Bjarne Stroustrup mentioned that there were proposals for keyword arguments; however, they were rejected, since

> the extensions group reached a consensus that the proposal was close to redundant, would cause compatibility problems with existing C++ code, and would encourage programming styles that ought not to be encouraged.

I suppose keyword template parameters were not included for the same reason. If you want to simplify your life, either `typedef` the complexity away, or write adapter classes that reorder the template parameters.

Comment: I know that it's the committee's opinion and not necessarily yours, but do you think you could elaborate on why this would be considered 'programming style that ought not to be encouraged'?

Comment: Sure. In python it is not uncommon to see functions with 10 or more parameters, most of them with defaults, that were made usable by keyword arguments. Having so many inputs is a bad code smell because such functions are difficult to maintain and are less coherent. The proposed refactor to such functions is to extract related arguments into separate structs that provide easy ways to create them.

Comment: It is important to try to stay on the high level of abstraction. `bool f(double, double, double, double, double, double, double)` does not tell you anything, `bool f(Point&, Point&, double)` starts to suggest what is happening :)

Comment: Apply the same reasoning for template parameters. You rarely ever need more than 3 -- if you do, your class might be doing too much. But if you had an easy way to templatise with 10 parameters, this would encourage people to do so

Answer (score 2):

No.

Template types are not supported like that. Types can be specified in place of the defaults in left to right order.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace by index, if the template fakes nothing but types.

Create the template with the first n args bound.  Then extract the arguments and replace the ones you want.

This requires the first n arguments be valid without the positional ones.

Sketch:

```
 template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
 template<class types, class T, size_t index>
 struct replace{
   using type=/*types with index replaced with `T`*/;
 };
 template<template<class...>class Z,class types>
 struct apply;// applies content of types to Z
 template<size_t n, class T>struct rep{};
 template<class Z, class...reps>
 struct replacing;
 template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts,class...reps>
 struct replacing<Z<Ts...>,reps...>:
   apply<Z,replacing_t<types<Ts...>,reps...>>
 {};
 template<class...Ts,class T0,class n,class...reps>
 struct replacing<types<Ts...>,rep<n,T0>,reps...>:
   replacing<replace_t<types<Ts...>,T0,n>,reps...>
 {};
 template<class...Ts>
 struct replacing<types<Ts...>>:
   types<Ts...>
 {};
```

with `_t` using aliases and a number of ops left blank.

Then you can:

```
 replacing_t<some_template<>,rep<1,int>>
```

which uses the default args of `some_template`, but replaces arg1 with `int`.